# Check Internet Connection using asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I'm checking the internet connection if it has an access on network but I always got an error of this in the line of  "listener.onComplete(b);" :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
02-01 14:03:09.660 I/MonoDroid(24139): at AppDesign.CheckInternetCon.RunInBackground (Java.Lang.Void[] params)
```

This is my code:
[image]
[image]

This is how I execute:

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Okay I will edit it

Comment: Quick look at screenshots, guessing your `listener` was never instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `ConnectivityManager` to check network availability. Use the following snippet to check connection.

You can call this function before making any network operations.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService
                (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected() && isConnectionAvailable(info)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isConnectionAvailable(NetworkInfo info) {
    return info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && info.getSubtype() != TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this..

To check whether a network connection is available use getActiveNetworkInfo()  method and isConnected().

```
 public boolean checkNetworkConnection()
 {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && (isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected())) {
        // show "Connected" & type of network "WIFI or MOBILE"
        tvIsConnected.setText("Connected "+networkInfo.getTypeName());
        // change background color to red
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7CCC26);


    } else {
        // show "Not Connected"
        tvIsConnected.setText("Not Connected");
        // change background color to green
        tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
    }

    return isConnected;
}
```